# Display table of distinct attribute values and their occurrence counts?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file with several nodes having the same identification number `id1`, `id2`, `id3`. I want to count nodes with the same id that contains a specific attribute, `attr = "ATR"`.

```
<ROOT>
<Node id="id1" att="Non" >
</Node >   
<Node id="id1" att="-" >
</Node >
<Node id="id1" att="ATR" >
</Node >   
<Node id="id1" att="ATR" >
</Node >   
<Node id="id2" att="Non" >
</Node >   
<Node id="id2" att="Non" >
</Node>   
<Node id="id2" att="ATR" >
</Node >
</ROOT>
```

Result should be displayed in a table

id1   2

id2   1

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us what you have tried, and tell us what language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

XSLT 2.0 has `distinct-values()` that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="/"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//*[@att='ATR']/@id)">
      <xsl:variable name="curId" select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($curId,' ',count($d//*[@att='ATR' and @id = $curId]))"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XSLT 1.0 Solution  <sub><sup><sub>*(Also works in XSLT 2.0)*</sub></sup></sub>

XSLT 2.0 lacks `distinct-values()`, but `xsl:key` and `generate-id()` can help instead to iterate over unique values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="idattr" match="//*[@att='ATR']/@id" use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@att='ATR']/@id[generate-id() = 
                                              generate-id(key('idattr', .)[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="curId" select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($curId, ' ', count(//*[@att='ATR' and @id = $curId]))"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both of the above solutions generate**

```
id1 2
id2 1
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can read the XML content and display it in html page:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>id1</td>
    <td id="id1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>id2</td>
    <td id="id2"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

The ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "main.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function (xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml), $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var data = xml.firstChild.children;
    var id1 = 0;
    var id2 = 0;
    for (var i= 0; i< data.length; i++){
        if ($(data[i]).attr('att') === "ATR"){
            $(data[i]).attr('id') == "id1" ? id1++ : id2++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = id1;
    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = id2;

}
});
```